# Pushing new messages with SignalR and SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr, sqldependency

I have a large table containing items that generally has a few new items inserted every second. I want to build a realtime application where users can subscribe to certain types of items and have a realtime feed whenever an item of a certain type is inserted.

As a start, I used
http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency but it is missing some crucial pieces that I am not sure how to implement.

What is the best way to track which messages to push to which clients? How can I track which messages have already been sent without the overhead of updating a "pushed" flag every time an update is received?

Comment: Ill have to follow along with the demo and take a look tonight if there is no answer.

Comment: Timestamps, compare state etc are the only way I'm afraid.

Comment: What if I created a different sqldependency for each "type" of item currently being monitored?  When a message is sent, the sqldependency query would be updated to where id>lastsent? Would this be the correct way to do it?

Comment: I took a quick look last night and could not find a better way than time stamps or a pushed flag.  Preference would be time stamps of pushed date since you would then also have history of when things were pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about the table changes. The test project for this component [does exactly the same functionality](http://sbl.azurewebsites.net/) what you are looking for. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

With SqlDependecyEx you are able to monitor INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE separately and receive actual changed data (`xml`) in the event args object. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR provides a Context.ConnectionId in the hub. You can use this as a key in a collection to track which items have been sent.

Here's an example from a logging chat application I wrote:

```
public class PushNotificationHub : Hub {        

    public void Send(string name, string message) {
        ChatService.ChatUsers[Context.ConnectionId].AddMessage(message);
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected() {
        ChatService.Current.LogMessage($"Client connected: {Context.ConnectionId}");
        ChatService.ChatUsers.Add(Context.ConnectionId, new Common.ChatUser(Context.QueryString["name"]));

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) {
        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).LogMessage($"Client disconnected: {Context.ConnectionId}"));
        ChatService.Current.LogMessage($"Client disconnected: {Context.ConnectionId}");
        ChatService.Current.LogMessage(ChatService.ChatUsers[Context.ConnectionId].PrintLog());

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```